Adjust contextMenu to only display card
I currently have a contextMenu attached to a PagedCarousel. This PagedCarousel has a:
includePageIndicator: true

modifier which displays which page the user is on when they scroll horizontally.
The contextMenu shouldn't have page indicator buttons on the bottom to be part of the highlighted context menu. Nor the gray edges. (Shown in Image) Click Here to See Image
How can I get the contexMenu to only highlight each card within the carousel?
Currently my PagedCarousel is structured this way:

if recentOrders.count > 1 {
                           PagedCarousel(items: recentOrdersByRegion,
                                              carouselType: .nonLazy,
                                              useFixedHeight: false,
                                              autoVerticalPadding: false,
                                              includePageIndicator: true,
                                              pageIndicatorCurrentElementLabelPath: 
                                              carouselLabel: localize(.recent).uppercased(),
                                              parentSize: geometry.size,
                                              content: { (order: Order) in
                                                
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    
                                              })

Attached under my PagedCarousel is my contextMenu:
.contextMenu {
                              ForEach(recentOrder) { order in
                                Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                                            dependencies.interactors.order
                                             .removeOrder(order)
                                        }, label: {
                                            Label("Remove", systemImage: "trash")
                                        })
                                    }
                                }

Im not sure why there are two remove buttons... but for now I would like some guidance on how to get the contextMenu to adjust to each card.
Since the contextMenu shouldn't be within the same scope of the PagedCarousel modifiers, Ive attempted to move the contextMenu to ensure that the modifiers don't interact with the menu.
contextMenu in Swift UI doesn't leave a lot of room for customization.
in this case I also attempted to turn the indicator bool to TRUE, which ofcourse disabled the page indicator on the PagedCarousel (which I don't want, only want to remove the indicators from the contextMenu)
Im pretty much stuck here

you could try using the other .contextMenu(forSelectionType: …) to specify a particular card.
See contextMenu.
The two buttons displaying is probably due to having two order in your recentOrder array in the ForEach.

thank you so much for the guidance. do you mean the "order"  initializer?
ForEach(recentOrder) { order in
Button(role: .destructive, action: {
dependencies.interactors.order
.removeOrder(order)
or the button with an action that calls the "dependencies.interactors.order" which removes the order from the stored data
OR do you mean the ".removeOrder(order)

I mean, you probably have two orders in your array recentOrder that you use in the ForEach(recentOrder). Can you check how many elements you have in recentOrder.

the recentOrder array used in the ForEach(recentOrder) is made up of a file containing several recentOrders the user can select from depending on their location

I managed to assign a view to the contextMenu, thank you so much! Now I am determined to figure out why the functionality is also not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
